# CSS transition disabled by `display:none`

Tags: css

I'm having an issue which seems to be preventing CSS transitions from playing on an element which is simultaneously changing from `display:none`.

In the following example, the divs have identical CSS, except that hovering over the first one hides the other two. The second div is hidden using `visibility:hidden`, and the third is hidden using `display:none`.

When you mouse over the first div, the behaviour is as expected: the first div transitions and the other two are hidden. When you mouse out, the behaviour is different from what I would expect: the first div transitions back to normal, the second div is unhidden then transitions back to normal, but the third div is unhidden and still in the normal state.

I was expecting for the third div to match the behaviour of the second and also be unhidden, then transition back to normal.

```css
div{
  width:100px;
  height:50px;
  background:red;
  
  border-radius:50%;
  
  transition: border-radius 1s;
}

#hover:hover, #hover:hover ~ div{
  border-radius:0%;
}

#hover:hover ~ #hide1{
  visibility:hidden;
}

#hover:hover ~ #hide2{
  display:none;
}
```

```html
<div id="hover">hover me for transition</div>
<div id="hide1">I transition back</div>
<div id="hide2">but I don't</div>
```

Since the second div works as expected, it's fairly easy to come up with alternate solutions using `visibility:hidden` and some positioning CSS, but is it possible to accomplish this in just CSS using `display:none`? If not, why does `display:none` affect other transitions in this way?

Note: This seems like something that would be easy to find, but my searches only turned up questions about attempting to transition the `display` property itself, not its side-effects on other transitions.

Comment: you can not apply transition on display property. for that you can use jQuery fadeIn/fadeOut.

Comment: @rmarif I'm not trying to transition the `display` property.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

A [simple explanation of `display: none`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/display):

> Turns off the display of an element (it has no effect on layout); all
>   descendant elements also have their display turned off. **The document
>   is rendered as though the element did not exist**.

(Emphasis mine)

The transition is not triggered because it was never started. The div was removed completely on hover and returned in its initial state with `border-radius: 50%`.

#### Workaround

The only possible way to achieve this affect with `display: none` using just CSS is to use an animation that will be triggered each time the `display: none` div appears.

```css
div {
  width: 100px;
  height: 50px;
  background: red;
  border-radius: 50%;
  transition: border-radius 1s;
  animation: display 1s;
}
#hover:hover,
#hover:hover ~ div {
  border-radius: 0%;
}
#hover:hover ~ #hide1 {
  visibility: hidden;
}
#hover:hover ~ #hide2 {
  display: none;
}
@keyframes display {
  0% {
    border-radius: 0;
  }
  100% {
    border-radius: 50%;
  }
}
```

```html
<div id="hover">hover me for transition</div>
<div id="hide1">I transition back</div>
<div id="hide2">but I don't (unless I have an animation)</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

No, you cannot use `display:none;`

Reason:

When using `display:none;` - The element will be hidden, and the page will be displayed as if the element is not there. So when you hover over it - the element is totally removed...and `border-radius:0%;` never gets applied. When you hover away - the element shows immediately as the css tells it to - with `border-radius:50%;`

`visibility:hidden;` hides an element, however the element will still take up the same space as before. The element will be hidden, **but still affect the layout.**

Answer (score -1):

You just can use `transition` for numerical properties in CSS, So you should use `opacity` and `transition: all 1s` to do this:

```css
div{
  width:100px;
  height:50px;
  background:red;
  
  border-radius:50%;
  
  transition: all 1s;
}

#hover:hover, #hover:hover ~ div{
  border-radius:0%;
}

#hover:hover ~ #hide1{
  visibility:hidden;
}

#hover:hover ~ #hide2{
  opacity: 0;
}
```

```html
<div id="hover">hover me for transition</div>
<div id="hide1">I transition back</div>
<div id="hide2">but I don't</div>
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but I think you've misread the question; it isn't about how to transition a div from visible to invisible, but about how to have transitions applied while also changing `display`.

Comment: @SeanLeBlanc So use jQuery, `.fadeIn()` and `fadeOut()` or `fadeToggle()`

Comment: I'm looking for a pure CSS solution, and again, I'm not trying to transition the visibility (i.e. fadein/fadeout), I'm trying to transition other properties (in this case `border-radius`) while the `display` property is changing instantaneously.

Answer (score -3):

```css
div{
  width:100px;
  height:50px;
  background:red;
  border-radius:50%;
  transition: border-radius 1s;
}

#hover:hover, #hover:hover ~ div{
  border-radius:0%;
}

#hover:hover ~ #hide1{
  visibility:hidden;
}

#hover:hover ~ #hide2{
  visibility: hidden;
}
```

```html
<div id="hover">hover me for transition</div>
<div id="hide1">I transition back</div>
<div id="hide2">but I don't</div>
```

This will work. On mouse out third div also have transition.

Comment: it is not possible in case of `display:None`

Comment: If it's not possible, do you happen to have an explanation for why?

Comment: `display:none;` will not be available in the page and does not occupy any space. `visibility:hidden` hides an element, but it will still take up the same space as before. The element will be hidden, but still affect the layout.

Comment: Yes, I already know that and mentioned in the question that it's easy to use `visibility:hidden` to accomplish the same effect with a bit of extra positioning CSS. I'm trying to find out how to produce the same behaviour using `display:none`, or an explanation as to why it isn't possible.

Comment: The 'visibility' property specifies whether the boxes generated by an element are rendered. `visibility:hidden;` :The generated box is invisible (fully transparent, nothing is drawn), but still affects layout. but in case of `display:None` an element do not appear in the formatting structure (i.e., in visual media the element generates no boxes and has no effect on layout). Descendant elements do not generate any boxes either; the element and its content are removed from the formatting structure entirely.a display of 'none' does not create an invisible box; it creates no box at all.

Comment: Again, this doesn't answer my question about transitions. I already know the layout difference between `visibility:hidden` and `display:none`; that is not what the question is about.

Comment: how can transition can be applied on element which is not even in the layout.

Comment: The issue shown by the example is that the transition is not being applied to an element which has just changed from `display:none` to `display:block`. It is in the layout during the transition period, but no transition appears to take place.